# Flash app working on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I'm making a tab app for a facebook fanpage in flash. The problem here is that in firefox the swf is loaded but, IS IN BLANK. Have you guys experienced this before? i just can't figure it out.

For embed the flash movie i'm using swfObject as flashdevelop always create for me.

Another thing is that i'm using the facebook graph api 1.8

In chrome works perfect. In Firefox i can't see my app.

Any ideas?

(I won't post any code because i'm sure that i'm not doing nothing strange with it)

Thanks

Francisco

Answer (score 1):

In firefox your flash player plugin is not updated you must update and restart -
[Adobe flash player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/%E2%80%8E)